# how to do different things in different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have made a program that computes the sum, difference, product and quotient of two numbers. I used threads to do this as follows

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThreadTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter 1st operand ::");
        int a = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter 2nd operand ::");
        int b = kb.nextInt();

        Addition add = new Addition(a, b);
        Subtraction sub = new Subtraction(a, b);
        Multiplication mul = new Multiplication(a, b);
        Division div = new Division(a, b);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(add);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(sub);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(mul);
        Thread t4 = new Thread(div);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
    }
}

class Addition implements Runnable
{
    int a, b;
    public Addition(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Addition :: " + (a+b));
    }
}


class Subtraction implements Runnable
{
    int a, b;
    public Subtraction(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Subtraction :: " + (a-b));
    }
}

class Multiplication implements Runnable
{
    int a, b;
    public Multiplication(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Multiplication :: " + (a*b));
    }
}

class Division implements Runnable
{
    int a, b;
    public Division(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Division :: " + (float)(a/b));
    }
}
```

Now what I want to know is that I needed to make a separate class for every operation I wanted to run in a separate thread so is there a way I can do it in one class and still have separate threads for every operator?

**Edit 1** Pseudocode:

```
class operators implements runnable{
     public void run1(){
     //some thing to do
     }
     public void run2(){
     //some thing to do
     }
}
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    //make object of operator class
    //make new thread for operator class' object
    //thread.start() should start all the run(run1, run2) methods at once
}
```

Basically, what I want is one class to have all the run functions(or whatever they are called) so it becomes less of a code to write and easier to start the threads.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards

Pranav Rastogi

Comment: I don't get what you expect exactly, could you reformulate somehow?

Comment: I want several threads to run at the same time without having a separate class for every thread.

Comment: the threads don't do the same computing so they have different classes, I still don't get it

Comment: I don't know if what I am asking for is even feasible so it is quite possible that what I am asking for is sheer nonsense so I'm sorry but what I am trying to get is something like class mathematics instead of separated classes like class addition, class subtraction, class multiplication etc.

Comment: add in your question what you would like to do ideally with pseudo code at least

Comment: It is not that mush clear, you already used separate class for each operation, and each one is use separate thread, so tell what do you u want in a short and clear sentences please.

Comment: @SirvanParaste what i want is to not create those separate classes but have a single class.

Comment: okay people I found that this cannot be done. Thanks for help everyone :)

Comment: everything could be done dear Pranav if you first imagine and tell what do you want we can help you, You can use an interface to define a mathematic operation and the implement that operation in separate class. when you trying to create the thread you want to do operation you can use that Interface as the parameter you want pass. it is called polymorphism, it is near to what u want I can help more by an example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your pseudocode, you can use inner classes implementing Runnable. One `Runnable` for each task.

```
 Runnable add = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              System.out.println("Addition :: " + (a+b));
          };
    };
```

And use a main Runnable to start the global tasks. This will be your resulting class. I guess the future use will be more complex

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThreadTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter 1st operand ::");
        int a = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter 2nd operand ::");
        int b = kb.nextInt();

        Operations op = new Operations (a,b);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(op);

        t1.start();

    }
}

class Operations implements Runnable{
    int a, b;
    public Operations(int a, int b){
         this.a = a;
         this.b = b;
    }
    public void run() {
        Runnable add = new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  System.out.println("Addition :: " + (a+b));
              };
        };    

        Runnable sub = new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  System.out.println("Subtraction :: " + (a-b));
              };
        };

        Runnable div = new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  System.out.println("Division :: " + (float)(a/b));
              };
        };

        Runnable mul = new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  System.out.println("Multiplication :: " + (a*b));
              };
        };

        Thread t1 = new Thread(add);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(sub);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(mul);
        Thread t4 = new Thread(div);

            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            t3.start();
            t4.start();
    }

}
```